# Redirection Issues in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

This is my .htacess in this I able to remove .php extension but it is not working as per expected output (eg. https://localhost/shap/example.php to https://localhost/shap/example) it is working for index.php but it is working for other .php page, it is been stuck in redirection
please help me get resolve this issue

error getting :
[image]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Return 404 if original request is .php
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
# RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://localhost/shap/ [NC,R]

RewriteRule ^example\.php$ https://localhost/shap/example[R]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you are hitting link `https://localhost/example/example.php` in browser?

Comment: here is the actual image @RavinderSingh13

Comment: You are hitting link `https://localhost/shap/example` which should be served by `https://localhost/shap/example.php` link in backend? Please confirm once.

Comment: it's eample.php only in backend but when I put this **RewriteRule ^example\.php$ https://localhost/shap/example[R]** to remove in htaccess its showing above error. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: So you are hitting `https://localhost/example/example.php` in browser?

Comment: yes @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Your folder name is `shap` or `example` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Make sure keep htaccess file root folder(along side with example folder NOT inside example folder).

Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/example/example\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /example/example? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(example)/(example)?$ $1/$2.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Ashish_more, Where is your htaccess and example.php located? Do give here complete path.

Comment: it is inside example folder @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Ashish_more, put htaccess along with example folder NOT inside example folder and try once?

Comment: no it did not work still giving same error@RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Ashish_more, could you please do mention what link you are using and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: can you specify which example  because i have mentioned only one example

Comment: @Ashish_more, My rules expecting that you are hitting link `https://localhost/example/example.php` in browser which should be redirecting to `https://localhost/example`? Is this the case.

Comment: **No** I want to redirect from **https://localhost/example/example.php** to **https://localhost/example/example** this. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @Ashish_more, Ok, keep your htaccess file inside root folder(NOT inside example folder, keep it along with example folder) and then try my edited Rules once? Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Ashish_more, Please do let me know if this solution has helped you?